# MSBuild autocorrects variable definitions without being told to

Tags: c#, msbuild

This is a very strange problem that I have run into. During my build, I have custom scripts that will run on certain files. One of these scripts will rewrite portions of the original file while creating a new file. Here is the target below:

```
<Target Name="GenerateWSHooksTarget" Outputs="%(AllFoundItems.Hooks)" Condition="'$(FoundFiles)'=='true'">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(AllFoundItems.FullPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileOutputEscaped"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <ItemGroup>
      <FileOutputEscaped>
        <Escaped>%(FileOutputEscaped.Identity)</Escaped>
        <Unescaped>$([MSBuild]::Unescape('%(FileOutputEscaped.Identity)'))</Unescaped>
      </FileOutputEscaped>
      <FileOutput Include="@(FileOutputEscaped->'%(Unescaped)')" />
    </ItemGroup>           

    <WSHooks ClassName="%(AllFoundItems.Classname)" ImportName="$(MSBuildProjectName)" FileData="@(FileOutput)">
      <Output TaskParameter="NewFileData" ItemName="WSHooksOutput"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="RewriteFileData" ItemName="WSRewriteOutput"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Changed" ItemName="WSHooksChanged"/>
    </WSHooks>

    <Message Importance="Normal" Text="Changed: @(WSHooksChanged)"/>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="%(AllFoundItems.Hooks)" Lines="@(WSHooksOutput)" Overwrite="True" />
    <WriteLinesToFile File="%(AllFoundItems.FullPath)" Lines="@(WSRewriteOutput)" Overwrite="True" Condition="@(WSHooksChanged)=='true'" />  
</Target>
```

It goes through 4 basic steps.

1. Read in all lines from the file
2. Unescape the lines from the read.
3. Pass the unescaped output to the custom task.
4. Write the output from the custom tasks to files.

Somewhere before the lines are passed to the custom task they are modified. It will change declarations from `Trade Trade = new Trade()` to `Trade trade = new Trade()` (I realize that the capital variable is bad practice, this is just one example that occured during my build.) The build also autocorrected a class from `ProductionFoecast` to `ProductionForecast`.

I have a feeling that StyleCop or FxCop is being run somehow, but I don't see it being run. I also am importing MSBuildExtensions task file, but only using it for searching right now.

Any ideas as to what is modifying my files before I get them in my custom task?

EDIT: Something I wanted to stress was this only happens on the declaration of the variable. So when it changes `Trade` to `trade` it only happens once, the rest of the occurrences of `Trade` are left as is. Naturally this breaks the build.

Comment: I just finished another test and it is not the `[MSBuild]::Unescape()` causing the problem. I just wrote a new file with the Escaped lines and they contained the changes. Is there some type of Target that would run before `BeforeBuild` that would hijack a read and point it to a file with modified contents?

Comment: Okay. I think I might have just had a breakthrough. I think the issue is stemming from `ReadLinesFromFile`. I used `$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(AllFoundItems.FullPath)))` and it didn't change variable names without notifying me. So I am going to try to create a custom read task and see if that solves my problems.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution so far has been to read the file in directly in the custom task. This isn't a very good solution because it doesn't explain why MSBuild became sentient and started correcting spelling, but it is a work around. I will leave the question unanswered in hopes someone will explain what was actually going on.

Comment: Clearly, MSBUILD has not become sentient. You have told it to run some other tool which is modifying the file. Try running [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out what is modifying the file, and perhaps to learn the nature of the modification.